# Integer Array Input in Python 2

Tags: python, arrays, input, integer

I am new to python. I want to take user inputs of 2 integer arrays a and b of size 4 and print them.
The input should be space seperated.

First user should input array a[] like this:

> 1 2 3 4

The he should input array b[] like this

> 2 3 4 6

The program should display a and b as output.I want the variables in a and b to be integers and not string.How do I this?

I was trying something like this

```
 a=[]
 b=[]
 for i in range(0,4):
         m=raw_input()
         a.append(m)
 for i in range(0,4):
         n=int(raw_input())
         b.append(n)

 print a
 print b
```

But this does not work.

Answer (score 4):

`raw_input` reads a single line and returns it as a string.

If you want to split the line on spaces a solution is

```
a = raw_input().split()
b = raw_input().split()
```

note that them will be arrays of **strings**, not of integers.
If you want them to be integers you need to ask it with

```
a = map(int, raw_input().split())
b = map(int, raw_input().split())
```

or, more explicitly

```
a = []
for x in raw_input().split():
    a.append(int(x))
b = []
for x in raw_input().split():
    b.append(int(x))
```

The Python interactive shell is a great way to experiment on how this works...

```
Python 2.7.8 (default, Sep 24 2014, 18:26:21) 
[GCC 4.9.1 20140903 (prerelease)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> "19 22 3 91".split()                                                        
['19', '22', '3', '91']
>>> map(int, "19 22 3 71".split())                                              
[19, 22, 3, 71]
>>> _
```

Comment: Thank you sir for your answer. Can you please tell me exactly where i should place the "for i in range(0,4):" for taking the values of 4 space seperated inputs from the user and what parts should be enclosed within the loop

Comment: @user220789: `str.split()` already does the needed loop internally and returns the list containing the spaces-separated parts; so `raw_input.split()` is already a list (but it's a list of substrings, not a list of ints).

Comment: So basically what happens here is that after I hit enter after the inputs, the new loop " for x in raw_input().split():
    b.append(int(x))" starts?So according to my understanding no checking for upper limit of array size occurs here I can enter any number of integers for a. Only when I hit enter the new list b begins.

Comment: @user220789: nothing happens when you hit space. Python `raw_input` always waits for you typing enter and then returns a string containing what you typed (including spaces): always a single string like e.g. `"1 2 3 4"`. Calling `split()` on that string returns `["1", "2", "3", "4"]`, i.e. a list of strings and then you need to convert them to integers. This can be done compactly with `map(int, ...)` or explicitly like in the two loops I've shown.

Comment: that was a typo, Sir I meant enter only. I have corrected my comment now.Thank you for your help, Sir.

Answer (score 3):

`raw_input()` reads a line from the user, that line needs to be splitted by space

```
a = raw_input().split()
b = raw_input().split()
```

Next, You'll need to convert the data to `int`
The easiest way to do that, is list comprehension

```
a = [int(x) for x in a]
b = [int(x) for x in b]
```

Answer (score 1):

Your program is working fine. You just didn't pass the `prompt string` which gets prompted on terminal to ask user's input:

```
a=[]
b=[]
for i in range(0,4):
    m=int(raw_input(" Enter value for a list :"))
    a.append(m)
for i in range(0,4):
    n=int(raw_input(" Enter value for b list :"))
    b.append(n)

print "list a looks like :-", a
print "list b looks like :-", b
```

This is how it will result:

```
 Enter value for a list :1
 Enter value for a list :2
 Enter value for a list :3
 Enter value for a list :4
 Enter value for b list :5
 Enter value for b list :6
 Enter value for b list :7
 Enter value for b list :8
list a looks like :- [1, 2, 3, 4]
list b looks like :- [5, 6, 7, 8]
```

---

```
raw_input(...)
    raw_input([prompt]) -> string

    Read a string from standard input.  The trailing newline is stripped.
    If the user hits EOF (Unix: Ctl-D, Windows: Ctl-Z+Return), raise EOFError.
    On Unix, GNU readline is used if enabled.  The prompt string, if given,
    is printed without a trailing newline before reading.
```

---

If you are expecting only `integers` as input you can use `input` built-in function, by which there is no need to type cast it again to integer.

```
a=[]
b=[]
for i in range(0,4):
    m = input(" Enter value for a list :")
    a.append(m)
for i in range(0,4):
    n = input(" Enter value for b list :")
    b.append(n)
```

```
input(...)
    input([prompt]) -> value

Equivalent to eval(raw_input(prompt)).
```

Answer (score 0):

From your description, I would code something like...

```
def foo():
    a = raw_input()
    a = a.split()
    a = [int(x) for x in a]
    if len(a) != 4:
            raise Exception("error: input 4 integers")
    b = raw_input()
    b = b.split()
    b = [int(x) for x in b]
    if len(b) != 4:
            raise Exception("error: input 4 integers")
    print a
    print b
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use python's sys module for reading input from command line.

```
import sys;
a = map(int, sys.stdin.readline().split());
b = map(int, sys.stdin.readline().split());
print a;
print b;
```

Comment: If you use python 3, you would need to do -> 
a = list(map(int, sys.stdin.readline().split()));
b = list(map(int, sys.stdin.readline().split()));

Answer (score 0):

**Here i have the complete code with example**

```
n=int(raw_input())
a=map(int,raw_input().split())
m=0
for i in range(n):
    print a[i]
```

**INPUT**

> 6
>
> 2 3 9 10 12 15

**OUTPUT**

> 2
>
> 3
>
> 9
>
> 10
>
> 12
>
> 15