# How can I get user input for an array?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to create a list from a user's input and then return a random value from that list.

This is what I have so far for the code but I can't figure out how to get input for the array.

```
import random
movie_array = ["movieA", "movieB", "movieC"]
print(random.choice(movie_array))
```

I know about the input function but I'm not sure how to use it to create an array/list.  I tried the following but it didn't work

```
movie_array = input()
```

but when I run the random.choice on that it only selects an individual character.

Comment: Try opening a scanner and asking the user to first input the number of elements in the array (size for array initialization), then use the same process to take n inputs.

Comment: @DebosmitRay: what is a `Scanner`? This is a question about Python, not Java.

Comment: This shows how to put user input into arrays: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27675035/integer-array-input-in-python-2

Comment: Please excuse the use of the word scanner. Python has this [input](http://anh.cs.luc.edu/python/hands-on/3.1/handsonHtml/io.html) function that you can use.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it like this:

```
>>> import random
>>> movie_array = [input("Input a movie: ") for i in  range(3)]
Input a movie: movieA
Input a movie: movieB
Input a movie: movieC
>>> print(random.choice(movie_array))
movieC
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a loop.

In the body of the loop prompt the user to enter a movie title, or 'q' to quit. Append each entry to your movie list. When finished select a random movie from the movie list:

```
import random

movies = []
while True:
    entry = input('Enter a movie title (q to quit): ')
    if entry.lower() == 'q':
        break
    movies.append(entry)

if movies:
    print(random.choice(movies))
```

Hopefully your users do not want to enter the movie entitled ["Q"](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0084556/) (1982). It might be better to use an empty entry as the sentinel, like this:

```
    entry = input('Enter a movie title (<Enter> to quit): ')
    if entry == '':
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

You can read movies in a single line separated by commas and then split it into array.

```
movie_array=raw_input("Enter Movies").split(',')
```

If it is python 3.x

```
movie_array=input("Enter Movies").split(',')
```

Comment: Many, many, if not most movie titles consist of more than one space separated word. Perhaps if the movies were separated with a comma instead?

Comment: Yes. I almost forgot that.

Answer (score 0):

Just want to clarify why your solution attempt didnt work IE this:

```
movie_array = input()
```

It's because the input returns a `string` I.E a list of *substrings* so 
you can see`movie_array = 'test'` as`movie_array = ['t','e','s','t']`

```
print(movie_array[1])
>>>'e'
```

in order to solve your problem I would recommend @mhawke answer (using a `while` loop)

By using a `while` loop you can retrieve multiple inputs and store each of them in a list. Be aware though that a while loop has to be able to *"END"* or it can cause problems. Therefore you have to have a `break` somewhere in the `while` loop.
Otherwise the program would be run indefinetly until you either forced it to shutdown or until it crashes.

Further information about this can be read here:

- [Tutorialspoint (Strings)](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_strings.htm)
- [Tutorialspoint (Whileloop)](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_while_loop.htm)

also checkout the official wiki for strings and control flow.

Answer (score -1):

You can give it like this.

```
movie_array = [b for b in input().split()]
```

And then you can get input from user like this,

```
movieA movieB movieC
```

Comment: 1. The list comprehension is pointless - `input().split()` already returns a list. 2. What if the user wanted to enter a movie title such as "Star Wars"? Splitting on whitespace will split that title into two - Star and Wars.