# Python how do it get pure data from user input in an entry widget=

Tags: python, string

I want to get the raw data from user input but i get it a string.

My goal is to get this:

```
X =[[8,5,3,9,1,4]]
```

Now i want the user to put in (Entry widget) 8,5,3,9,1,4

So i saved it in a variable like :

```
Y= entry.get()
```

```
X = [[Y]]
```

Now Y is from data type String so what i get is:

```
X=[["8,5,3..."]]
```

But I want the 'pure' data like 8,5,7... not a string '8,5,7'. What can I do?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Integer Array Input in Python 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27675035/integer-array-input-in-python-2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "I want to get the raw data from user input but i get it a string."

Well, this actually **is** "the raw data".

> what i get is `X=[["8,5,3..."]]` But i want the "pure" data like 8,5,7.

So you're question is "how do I parse a list of comma-separated digit characters into a list of ints". Which is quite simple actually: split the string on comma, pass each part to `int`, and collect the result:

```
X = [[int(part.strip()) for part in Y.strip().split(",")]]
```

Note that this will break if the user doesn't follow the expected input format - but well, that's not part of the question (hint: you can either pre-validate the input format with a regexp, or catch exceptions).

Comment: And what if the list contains ints and floats for example like : 8,4,4,1,6.1,10,2,5,2 now there is 6.1 in it but it will cause an error cuz of int(part.strip). can i also parse ints and floats?

Comment: @Arrogant then your best bet is probably to treat everything as floats. Ìf for any reason you _really_ need to keep ints as ints, you can test if `part` contains a dot and select the desired type accordingly.

Comment: It worked thanks for your help...  I really appreciate it